# Web API: POST Array data

Tags: arrays, post, asp.net-web-api

I want to send obj array to sql, but I have no idea what's the syntax is.

I Already try this tutorial and nothing works for me.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fe_NKU-UbkI&t=317s
(edit:)maybe I'm really just noob and didn't get the function of the tutorial syntax.

this code below works and send obj on sql one by one. yes it won't work on accepting array, that's my problem what is the syntax for that? I'm using GUI MVC to send obj to my sql

```
//Employee Controller
//POST: api/Employee
[ResponseType(typeof(Employee))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostEmployee(Employee employee)
{
     db.Employees.Add(employee);
     await db.SaveChangesAsync();
     return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = employee.GuID }, employee);
}


//Json playing on Insomia Third Party App i just make it to array now so you have an idea what i'm trying to send to my sql.
POST:http://localhost:58482/api/Employee/
[{
    GuID: "1",
    Name: "Vegita",
    Age: "31",
    Address: "Pluto",
},
{
    GuID: "2",
    Name: "San Goku",
    Age: "33",
    Address: "Earth",
}]
```

Working Syntax that will post array of obj on my sql.
Im noob at WEBAPI please be gentle, just wanted to learn complicated stuffs for myself and thank you!

Comment: i'm not using WebAPI-Core etc.

Comment: do you want to use AJAX post or HttpClient? also your parameter is Employee can not put array in this

Comment: i might give it a try, what do you recommend to those two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass List employee as paramter of your API

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/CusActivity/PostEmployee")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostEmployee(List<Employee> employee)
    {
        //db.Employees.Add(employee);
        //await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        //return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = employee.GuID }, employee);
        return null;

    }
```

In HTML you can use AJAX to POST data

```
 var employees = [
        {
            Name: 'Test1'
        },
        {
            Name: 'Test2'
        }
    ];
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:56433/api/CusActivity/PostEmployee',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(employees),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) { console.log(data); }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

this answer work on me and give the output I wanted.

```
//Employee Controller
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Employee")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostEmployee([FromBody]Employee[] employee)
    {
        using (var db = new DBModels())
        {
            foreach (Employee E in employee)
            {
                db.Employees.Add(E);
            }
            int n = db.SaveChanges();
            return Created("api/Employee", n);
        }
    }

//my json that i ran on Insomia App.
//POST: api/Employee
    [{
        GuID: "7",
        Name: "Vegita",
        Age: "21",
        Address: "Pluto",
    },
    {
        GuID: "8",
        Name: "San Goku",
        Age: "20",
        Address: "Mars",
    }]
```